# Redis query is showing only 10 results while searching for a particular data

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis, redisearch

I have a .net core microservice integrated with Redis/RediSearch. I do a search that should return 13 hash documents but returns only 10. In elasticSearch there is a default size parameter(10) but in Redis I didn't find similar. How can I solve ?

```cs
public  List<DynamicDoc> GetFullMoc(string queryParm){
    var redisConection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetParameter("REDIS_SERVER"));
    var dbRedis = new Client("feeders", redisConection.GetDatabase());

    string searchString = "@MOC:" + queryParm;
    NRediSearch.Query query = new NRediSearch.Query(searchString);
    
    string[] returnFields = { "Moc", "H_W","H_Y", "F"};
    query.ReturnFields(returnFields);
    query.WithPayloads = true;

    SearchResult res =  dbRedis.Search(query);
    List<DynamicDoc> dynamicDocs = new List<DynamicDoc>();


    foreach (Document doc in res.Documents)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, RedisValue>> record = doc.GetProperties();
        string jsonRecord = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record);
        Dictionary<string, object> _record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonRecord);
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n ================" + doc.Id + "================ \n \n \n");
        foreach(var rec in _record){
            Console.WriteLine(rec);
        }
        
        DynamicDoc dynamicDoc = new DynamicDoc()
        {
                id = doc.Id,
                score = doc.Score,
                payload = _record
        };
        dynamicDocs.Add(dynamicDoc);
        
    }
    return dynamicDocs;

}
```

DynamicDoc:

```cs
namespace cached_data_manager.Business.Interface
{
    public class DynamicDoc
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double score { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> payload{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`FT.SEARCH` command has a optional `LIMIT` parameter which takes two arguments, `offset` and `num`. The default values are 0 and 10 respectively.

From the command description:

> **LIMIT first num** : Limit the results to the offset and number of results given. Note that the offset is zero-indexed. The default is 0 10, which returns 10 items starting from the first result.

Here is the complete command description: https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch

---

To do it programmatically, use the `Limit` option in NRediSearch.Query. E.g.

```
query.Limit(0, 10000);
```

Comment: I understood! I can do it with rediSearch from the terminal, but programmatically I don't know how to do it. Can you help me ?

Comment: That's correct. You can use Limit Option in Quey as explained above. Example : query.Limit(offset: 0, count: 100);